# undefined object (evaluating '_reactNavigation.ThemeColors.light')

Tags: react-native, npm

I am working on atome and I use NPM with react-native.

I got this error when I try to start my application :

> TypeError undefined is not an object(evaluating
>   '_reactNavigation.ThemeColors.light')

I searched a lot and nothing work for me.

This is the error on my phone:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install the following version:

"react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",

"react-native-reanimated": "^1.2.0",

"react-navigation": "^4.0.5",

"react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.1",

"react-navigation-stack": "^1.8.0",

"react-navigation-tabs": "^2.5.3"

The problem is probably in your react-navigation version you need to install the 4.x version

Comment: How do you install the 4.x version?

Comment: npm install react-navigation@4.0.5

Comment: I had to also install `react-native-screens`